# mouseover doesn't work on d3 rectangle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I am new at d3. I have written the below code for 3 rectangles to appear and make them have some mouse interaction.

```
svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")
            .data([1,2,3])
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x",function(d,i){return 600+i*50;})
            .attr("y",30)
            .attr("width",40)
            .attr("height",40)
            .attr("fill","blue")
            .on("mouseover",function(d) {

            d3.select(this).append("text")
                .attr("y", "100")
                .attr("x", "500")
                .attr("class", "hover")                 
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                        .attr("font-size", "12px")
                .style("fill",  "black")
                .text(function(d){console.log("mouseover");
                return "Text I want";})
            })

            .on("mouseout", function(d) {

                d3.select(this).select("text.hover").remove();
            })
            .on("click",function(d){console.log(d);
                if(d==1)
                Pie(array1,array2);
                if(d==2)
                Pie(array3,array4);
                if(d==3)
                Pie(array5,array6);

            })
            .style("opacity",1e-6)
             .transition()
             .duration(1000)
             .style("opacity",0.8);
```

The `console.log("mouseover")` appears at the console, but no text is shown at the browser. The click event works with pie charts being constructed. Can anybody spot what is going wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mouseover:

```
d3.select(this).append("text")
```

would append the `text` to the `rect` but `rect` elements can not have children.

Changing it to:

```
svg.append("text")
```

works.  Full code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);
  
    svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")
      .data([1, 2, 3])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return 10 + i * 50;
      })
      .attr("y", 30)
      .attr("width", 40)
      .attr("height", 40)
      .attr("fill", "blue")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {

        svg.append("text")
          .attr("y", "100")
          .attr("x", "200")
          .attr("class", "hover")
          .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
          .attr("font-size", "12px")
          .style("fill", "black")
          .text(function(d) {
            console.log("mouseover");
            return "Text I want";
          })
      })

    .on("mouseout", function(d) {

        svg.select("text.hover").remove();
      })
      .on("click", function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        if (d == 1)
          Pie(array1, array2);
        if (d == 2)
          Pie(array3, array4);
        if (d == 3)
          Pie(array5, array6);

      })
      .style("opacity", 1e-6)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 0.8);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I wanted. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use d3-tip module for d3. It provides very nice hover tooltip

http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

```
var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function(d) {
     return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
 })
```

and on bars or rectangles use

```
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing me to tooltips. I used them for other parts of my code.

Comment: For compatibility with d3 v4 use this branch: https://github.com/VACLab/d3-tip/blob/master/d3-tip.js